# Help wanted. paced - populated Dictionary not saved

Tags: spell-checking

i managed to install and configure the paced package.
My system is Emacs "GNU Emacs 26.1 (build 1, x86_64-w64-mingw32)
 of 2018-05-29" on Windows 8.1 64.
Unfortunately the paced dictionary is not saved after repopulated.
I don't know why.
Does anybody here successfully use the package?

```
My config:
;; paced-mode
(require 'paced)
;; Activate paced
(global-paced-mode)
;; Load paced dictionaries
(setq paced-dictionary-directory "~/.emacs.d/paced-dictionaries/")
(paced-load-all-dictionaries)
;; Save paced dictionaries after repopulating them
(setq paced-repopulate-saves-dictionary t)
;; ;; Load async paced settings
(setq paced-async-load-file "~/.emacs.d/paced-async-mein.el")
;;(load "paced-async.el")
;; Enable Default dictionary in Org, markdown, and text modes
(setq paced-global-dictionary-enable-alist '((t . "Default")))
;;(setq paced-global-dictionary-enable-alist '((my-paced-files-check-p . 
"Default")))
(setq paced-throw-error-on-no-current nil)
;; Repopulate the current dictionary after saving
(add-hook 'after-save-hook 'paced-repopulate-current-dictionary-async)
(define-advice ispell-pdict-save (:after (&optional _no-query _force-save) 
paced-populate)
;; Repopulate the current dictionary after running spell check
(paced-repopulate-current-dictionary-async))
;; In Org-mode capf auf M-# setzen, da TAB Sonderfunktionen besitzt.
(global-set-key (kbd "M-#") 'completion-at-point)

Generator : (lambda nil org-agenda-files
Sort Method : paced--default-dictionary-sort-fun
```

The exclude function from the website is not working correct, because if activated then no words are inside the dictionary.
After check a buffer the command paced-print-current-dictionary shows words.
But after save and close buffer the dictionary is empty.
Strange.

Regards
Poul

Comment: Have you tried asking the package maintainer?

Comment: Yes and No. With the help of the maintainer i managed it to run. But about this problem, i got no answer until now.
Does it mean, that here is the wrong place?

Comment: This is also a good place to ask, but I don't how many people actually use this package, it is new to me.  The information you give about the status of input from the maintainer is helpful.  What you describe sounds like a bug, it does not do what the documentation advertises, and it is good you opened an issue on the project's homepage  But may be someone here can see what fix is needed.

Comment: One thought, you have commented out the loading of `paced-async.el`.  Is this not needed for your set-up?